# String to indicator variable, type mismatch error

Tags: string, stata, type-mismatch

I am trying to convert a string variable (type `str2`, format `%9s`) into an indicator variable in Stata.

However, I keep receiving the following error:

> type mismatch r(109)

I am using the 2016 ANES set and I am essentially trying to group states into open primary and closed primary/caucus states.

I have attempted the following code:

```
gen oprim= (state=="AL" & "AK" & "CO" & "GA" &...)

gen oprim=1 if state=="AL" & "AK" & "CO" & "GA" &...
```

I have had trouble converting this variable before. for example, I tried generating the new indicator variable without putting quotations around the state codes.

I have also tried to `destring` the variable, but I am receiving the following output:

```
destring state, generate(statenum) float
state: contains nonnumeric characters; no **generate**
```

Any help anyone could offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide example data using `dataex`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438117/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's spell out *why* the code in the question is wrong. The OP doesn't give example data but the errors are all identifiable without such data, assuming naturally that `state` is a string variable in the dataset.

First, we can leave out the `...` (which no one presumes are legal) and the parentheses (which make no difference).

```
gen oprim = state=="AL" & "AK" & "CO" & "GA"

gen oprim=1 if state=="AL" & "AK" & "CO" & "GA"
```

Either of these will fail because Stata parses the `if` condition as

`if`

`state == "AL"`

`& "AK"`

`& "CO"`

`& "GA"`

`state == "AL"` is a true-or-false condition evaluated as 0 or 1, but none of `"AK"` `"CO"` `"GA"` is a true or false condition; they are all string values and so the commands fail, because Stata needs to see something numeric as each of the elements in a `if` condition. Although clearly silly,

`gen oprim = state == "AL" & 42`

would be legal as 42 is numeric (and in true-or-false evaluations counts as true). Stata won't fill in `state ==`, which is what you hope to see implied.

If you rewrite

```
gen oprim = state == "AL" & state == "AK" & state == "CO" & state == "GA"
```

then you have a legal command. It's just not at all what you evidently want. It's impossible for `state` to be equal to different string values in the same observation, which is what this command is testing for. You're confusing `&` (and) with `|` (or).

```
gen oprim = state == "AL" | state == "AK" | state == "CO" | state == "GA"
```

Such statements get long and are tedious and error-prone to write out, but Stata has alternative syntax

```
gen oprim = inlist(state, "AL", "AK", "CO", "GA")
```

There are limits to that -- and yet other strategies too -- but I will leave this answer there without addressing further issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first ten observations of the `census` toy dataset:

```
sysuse census, clear
keep if _n <= 10
```

The following works for me:

```
generate oprim = 0 
replace oprim = 1 if state2 == "AZ" | state2 == "DE"

list state2 oprim, separator(0)

     +----------------+
     | state2   oprim |
     |----------------|
  1. | AL           0 |
  2. | AK           0 |
  3. | AZ           1 |
  4. | AR           0 |
  5. | CA           0 |
  6. | CO           0 |
  7. | CT           0 |
  8. | DE           1 |
  9. | FL           0 |
 10. | GA           0 |
     +----------------+
```